# BigQuery issue on Tableau

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, tableau-api

We can't get the BigQuery data that came from Google Analytics Premium on Tableau recently. It used to work.

It returns the error message like this

The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
Unrecognized name: `device.browser` at [1:8]

The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
Unrecognized name: `customDimensions.index`; Did you mean customDimensions? at [1:80]

As we haven't done on changes on BigQuery structure. Any idea to solve the issue?

Comment: can you provide the query you are using between BigQuery and Tableau?

Comment: I have the same problem. Getting an error `The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
Unrecognized name: \`customDimensions.index\`; Did you mean customDimensions? at [1:80]`. Did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have nested fields in your table

**Solution**: I solved it by creating a view in which I provided an alias name for each nested column(something like `parent.child1 as parent_child1` and `parent.child2 as parent_child2`).

Then referenced the View in Tableau.